# Sort two lists together in scala

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

Say I have two lists:

```
List(("a",1),("b",4),("d",5),("a",7),("b",6))
```

and

```
List("a","b","c","d")
```

and I want to group them based on the first list such that I get:

```
List("a" -> List(("a",1),("a",7)), "b" -> List(("b",4),("b",6)), "d" -> List(("d",5)))
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? I know I can use groupBy and pattern match against pre-determined values but when the second list is not pre-determined I get a little stuck.

Edit:

I need a copy of the object in the second list as the key for the processed list. I might need to group by a parameter of an on object in the second list but still maintain the entire object as the key... if that makes sense.

```
List(("a",1),("b",4),("d",5),("a",7),("b",6)) 
List(("a",1,1),("b",2,3),("c",5,6),("d",6,7))
```

becomes:

```
 List(("a",1,1) -> List(("a",1),("a",7)), ("b",2,3) -> List(("b",4),("b",6)), ("d",6,7) -> List(("d",5)))
```

Sorry for lack of clarity!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per your edit, with a `for`-comprehension:

```
for {
  key <- second
  pair <- first.groupBy(_._1).get(key)
} yield key -> pair
```

Or the unsugared equivalent:

```
second.flatMap(key => first.groupBy(_._1).get(key).map(key -> _))
```

Both of these perform the `groupBy` operation for every key. If this is an issue you can of course avoid it with the slightly more verbose:

```
val mappings = first.groupBy(_._1)
second.flatMap(key => mappings.get(key).map(key -> _))
```

And to address your new edit: if you need to transform each item in the second list to use it as a key for the first, there are a couple of ways you can go about that. For example, given:

```
val first = List(("a", 1), ("b", 4), ("d", 5), ("a", 7), ("b", 6))
val second = List(("a", 1, 1), ("b", 2, 3), ("c", 5, 6), ("d", 6, 7))
```

Either:

```
for {
  item @ (key, _, _) <- second
  pair <- first.groupBy(_._1).get(key)
} yield item -> pair
```

Or:

```
for {
  item <- second
  pair <- first.groupBy(_._1).get(item._1)
} yield item -> pair
```

Works as desired.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is surprisingly simple:

```
first groupBy(_._1) toList
```

Result:

```
List((a,List((a,1), (a,7))), (d,List((d,5))), (b,List((b,4), (b,6))))
```

Where `first` is your first list (what is the purpose of the second one)?

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

```
val first = List(("a",1),("b",4),("d",5),("a",7),("b",6))
val second = List(("a",1,1),("b",2,3),("c",5,6),("d",6,7))
first groupBy {k => second find {_._1 == k._1} get}
```

Comment: This doesn't maintain the order, which seems to be one of the requirements.

Comment: While you could always add `toList.sortBy{_._1._1}`, I shall continue to selfishly assume that he doesn't need to preserve ordering until it is explicitly stated :)

Answer (score -1):

```
val a = List(("a",1),("b",4),("d",5),("a",7),("b",6))
val b = List(("a",1,1),("b",2,3),("c",5,6),("d",6,7))
val a1 = a.groupBy{ _._1 }
b.flatMap{ x => a1.get(x._1).map{x -> _} }
```

or

```
val a = List(("a",1),("b",4),("d",5),("a",7),("b",6))
val b = List(("a",1,1),("b",2,3),("c",5,6),("d",6,7))
b.view.map{ x => x -> a.filter{ _._1 == x._1 } }.filter{ _._2.nonEmpty }.toList
```

The second approach should be the most efficient.